# Ubuntu screen freezes when app in fullscreen but mouse moves

Tags: 18.04, freeze, fullscreen

I installed **Ubuntu 18.04.1** but sometimes my screen freezes and forces me to reboot my system.

I tried to find a solution on internet but I didn't found anything similar to this:

When I am with an **app in fullscreen**, the screen eventually freezes letting me **only move the mouse** and **pressing *Ctrl+Alt+(F1-F7)***.

I dont know which steps I have to do to cause the error, but seems that *Alt+Tab* to move from the fullscreen app to other things produce it frequently.

I cant aply solutions like *Alt+F2*, they don't do anything

It may be usefull to know that the apps still runs. I was playing in RetroArch when the screen freezes, but the game sound was ok, and it corresponded to my controller inputs.

Does it happend to anyone or do anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Having the same issue from a few weeks on the same Ubuntu version (18.04.1).

Comment: Upgraded to 18.04 day before. Exactly same issue at my end. Not sure about the solution yet.